# Is there a way to parse through all Wikipedia articles that are related to the heart?

Tags: wikipedia

How can I iterate through all articles on Wikipedia related to a topic?

I tried to compile a list of all articles related to the heart by visiting each article in [the wikipedia category for "Heart"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Heart), but that list seems incomplete. It also includes links to heart used outside of a biological context. Is there a way to restrict the query to only the biologically-related articles?

Comment: use dbpedia, sparql, etc.

Comment: To get the list of all articles on a topic, use WikiData, https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=heart+AND+%28cardiac+OR+cardio+OR+muscle+OR+muscular+OR+organ+OR+body%29+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 seems to give a list of everything related to hearts on wikipedia.